# How to set a Windows Start Menu Layout via PowerShell for the current user on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

Since I had to set up Windows PCs way too often in the last time (and probably will also in the next time) I am working on automating this process as much as I possibly can (even though it still won't be worth it timewise).

Currently I try to erase all items from the start layout. I have seen [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1068382/how-to-remove-all-the-tiles-in-the-windows-10-start-menu) but it states there *it only unpins installed applications* (some stuff will still be there after executing the script like the Windows Store).

So instead I thought it would be easier to just say Windows "Hey, how about using this empty layout" to remove everything. I followed these both tutorials [1](https://winaero.com/blog/default-start-menu-layout-windows-10/), [2](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/105001-set-default-start-layout-users-windows-10-a.html).

I exported my current (empty) start layout via PowerShell:

```
Export-StartLayout -UseDesktopApplicationID -Path "C:\CustomStartLayout.xml"
```

It looks like this:

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
    <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
    <DefaultLayoutOverride>
        <StartLayoutCollection>
            <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" />
        </StartLayoutCollection>
    </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Then I created the registry entries as they are in both tutorials:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer"
New-ItemProperty -Force -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer -Name LockedStartLayout -PropertyType DWord -Value 0
New-ItemProperty -Force -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer -Name StartLayoutFile -PropertyType ExpandString -Value "C:\CustomStartLayout.xml"
```

It states that the changes should take effect after restarting Windows, but they don't. I already checked whether the registry keys are in the registry with correct values at the correct path and that the xml file is at the correct path.

Am I missing something? Or is there another approach? It is important that I just have to execute the script in the end and that I do not have to interfere with anything manually. Manual steps should only be initial (like writing this script or creating a standard layout file which will later be loaded in).

Comment: I do not know if this your issue, but I had to delete the old .xml file.  After I deleted the .xml I could swap in the new .xml.   The creation date of the .xml must be newer than the one you replaced.  I never edited the the registry.

Comment: I do it with a local group policy and give a local path to the xml file.
You may need to put the xml to a folder (mine is in C:\Something) so you can delete the user profile and try it. In my case if the profile is already done then is not working.

Comment: These both things did not work but I discovered how I can do what I want to do. I'll post it any minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a bit of research. Apparently, it is somehow special to apply a start layout to a user that is currently logged in (because this is not needed often and only applies to one single user).

The above solution in my question only works for users that did not log into the system on this computer yet - not even once (**I did not test it** with a newly created user. I just know my PC didn't explode after running these commands).

From [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21b078c9-6f73-4647-8d2e-2800aba475ce/start-menu-layout-for-current-user-on-windows-10-1607?forum=win10itprogeneral) and [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1068648/configuration-file-for-the-start-menu-in-windows-10) I now know that the default configuration of the start layout lies at:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayout.xml
```

And also that this one should not be changed. For modifications use the following file (if it is not present yet, just create it):

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml
```

But this file will only take effect after deleting a specific registry item. Here is how you do it in PowerShell:

```
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store"
```

Of course, Windows Explorer needs to be restarted afterward for the effects to take place.

Comment: The PC doesn't need to be restarted, but Windows explorer does.
This can easily be done from task manager

Comment: Yes, you are right. I always do that the same way, I don't know why I wrote it that way at that time. I'll update it.